# SCSS class names with values as input

Tags: sass, interpolation

I am trying to make a css class that can use a number as input for a style associated with the class.  For example:

```
.font-<size> {
  font-size: <size>px;
}
```

where 'size' is a number.

Is this possible with scss?

---

MY SOLUTION:

---

This is what I ended up doing which is hard coded but gets the job done:

```
 // Generates some useful quick font size classes
$f-sizes: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30;
@each $i in $f-sizes {
  &.font-#{$i*2}:before {
    font-size: #{$i*2}px;
  }
}
```

Which will allow me to access font sizes 2 through 60 via class .font-28.

Comment: bro.. why u do this -1

Answer (score 0):

You would need a mixin. 
http://thesassway.com/advanced/pure-sass-functions

```
@mixin size-mixin($some-number) {
  font-size: $some-number;
}
```

Then you would just include this mixing on your classes.

```
.font-class {
  @include size-mixin(10px);
}
```

Comment: yes but can the actual class name be used give the 10px into the mixin?  It looks like this would be hard coded like the answer by @bass-jobsen

Comment: what are you trying to do? sass works by generating css for you, but does not process css on the fly so that if you have a class named font-size-{number} it would read the number and generate the styles needed. you can utilize mixins to create various classes with different properties without retyping in all the data, but i do not think you would be able to do what you are looking to do.

Comment: ahh right that is true.  So this is impossible to do.  Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

```
$number: 10;

.font-#{$number} {
  font-size: #{$number}px;
}
```

The SCSS code above compiles into CSS code as follows:

```
.font-10 {
  font-size: 10px; }
```

Comment: this is not answering my question.  I don't want to ever set $number, I want this to be passed in from my markup...

Comment: i do not understand your question. SCSS precompiles into static CSS code "knowing" nothing about your HTML